# Facebook app scoped user id's temporary

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to see who is going to a Facebook event, so I use the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending) to get the attendees. The users I get have an app scoped user id.

But here is the thing: sometimes the same user gets a different App Scoped User Id. So for example, the user John Doe first has an app scoped user id of 1000000, and a week later it is 2000000.

I get redirected to the same John Doe profile when I visit these urls:

- facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1000000
- facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/2000000

Are these app scoped user ids temporary ids?

**Edit:**

This is the API call I use to get the event attendees:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/EVENT_ID_HERE/attending?access_token=app_id|app_secret

Answer (score 0):

App Scoped IDs are definitely not temporary if the user authorized your App. If the same user gets a different App Scoped ID, then i assume it´s because he is did NOT authorize your App. It makes sense, because non-authorized users should not be stored. If you think that this is a bug, you should file a report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I just get the users that are attending an event, I don't (also can't) ask each of them permission

Comment: that´s what i thought. you are not supposed to store any data of those, unless they specifically allowed it (by authorizing your app and accepting your privacy policy). i assume that´s why the IDs are changing.

Comment: Did you read this somewhere in the documentation? Why would facebook even bother to return an app scoped user id if its temporary?

Comment: not sure, and i didn´t read it in the documentation, but it does make sense to keep them temporary. you can still use the id to show them somewhere short term, and the id even makes sense for that. but about not storing data of people without their consent, that´s a general privacy rule not just valid for facebook.

Comment: I thought it was allowed to store a app scoped user id. Which would make sense because you can compare it against users of an event. But you could be right and this app scoped user id is temporary, but is it possible to ask Facebook somehow?

Comment: this would be the perfect place to ask: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: I posted the question there, but they say the app scoped user ids are permanent. Which would make this a bug. https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/915175161859332/

Comment: yup, in that case just file a bug

Comment: did you try with authorized users btw? those app scoped ids should definitely be permanent.

Comment: I have some authorised users but not a lot. This issue really comes from the many app scoped user ids I get from users attending events. Its too bad there is no way of asking facebook directly. Maybe this app scoped user id thing was pushed to fast to get some heat off the privacy debate.

Comment: well, you already did ask facebook directly. there are many facebook employees in the group on facebook ;)